# Least Common Multiple and the product of a sequence of consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, least-common-multiple

Let $x>0, n>0$ be integers.

Let LCM$(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)$ be the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$.

Let $v_p(u)$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $u$.

It seems to me that:

$$\frac{(x+1)(x+2)\times\dots\times(x+n)}{\text{LCM}(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)} \le (n-1)!$$

Here is my thinking:

- Let $p$ be any prime that divides $(x+1)\times\dots\times(x+n)$.
- Let $x+i$ be the integer in $\{x+1,x+2. \dots, x+n\}$ that is divisible by the highest power of $p$.
- All integers in the sequence $\{x+1, x+2, x+3, \dots, x+n\}$ that are divisible by $p$ will have the form $x + i \pm ap$ where $0 < a \le \left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{p}\right\rfloor$.
- $v_p\left(\dfrac{(x+1)(x+2)\times\dots\times(x+n)}{\text{LCM}(x+1,x+2,\dots,x+n)}\right) \le v_p(p) + v_p(2p) + \dots + v_p\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{p}\right\rfloor p\right) = v_p((n-1)!)$
- So, it follows that the maximum power of $p$ that divides $\dfrac{(x+1)\times\dots\times(x+n)}{\text{LCM}(x+1,\dots,x+n)}$ is less than or equal to the maximum power of $p$ that divides $(n-1)!$

---

Edit:  Made changes to third and fourth bullet point with an attempt to make them cleaner.

Based on feedback received.

---

Edit 2:  I originally put the "same" power in the last bullet point.  That is not correct.  It should be less or equal.  I have changed it.

---

Edit 3:  Fixed a typo.  n! should be (n-1)!.

Comment: Are the third and fourth parts in your thinking saying that $v_p((x+1)\cdots (x+n))\le v_p(x+i)+\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p}\rfloor$ ? If not, can you make it clearer?

Comment: @mathlove, thanks for the feedback.  I have cleaned up the text in the question.   I hope that my thinking is now clearer.

Comment: OK, I'll read them carefully. By the way, the last bullet point is not true in general. Take $x=1,n=9,p=2$.

Comment: Very good point.  The maximum power is less or equal not necessarily the same. I will update the argument.

Comment: *Interpreted literally*, the third bullet point is not ture. Take $x=3,n=3,p=2$. Then, $x+i-p$ is not in $\{x+1,\cdots, x+n\}$. Also, in the fourth bullet point, the equation $v_p(p) + v_p(2p) + \dots + v_p\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{p}\right\rfloor p\right) = v_p(n!)$ is not true. Take $n=8,x=1,p=2$.

Comment: hmm, maybe I've misunderstood the third bullet point, sorry. Please forget the part about the third bullet point in my previous comment.

Comment: The 4th point should be (n-1)!.  That was a typo.  I will fix.

Comment: I've just found [a wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) that is saying your claim is true.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the link.  If you want to put that as the answer to this question, I am glad to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is true according to [a wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas).

Changing $n,k$ to $x+n,n-1$ respectively in$$\binom nk\le\frac{\text{LCM}(n-k,n-k+1,\cdots, n)}{n-k}$$
we get
$$\binom{x+n}{n-1}\le\frac{\text{LCM}(x+1,x+2,\cdots, x+n)}{x+1}$$
which is your claim.